# Need help working with lists within lists

Tags: python-3.x

I'm taking a programming class and have our first assignment.  I understand how it's supposed to work, but apparently I haven't hit upon the correct terms to search to get help (and the book is less than useless).

The assignment is to take a provided data set (names and numbers) and perform some manipulation and computation with it.

I'm able to get the names into a list, and know the general format of what commands I'm giving, but the specifics are evading me.  I know that you refer to the numbers as names[0][1], names[1][1], etc, but not how to refer to just that record that is being changed.  For example, we have to have the program check if a name begins with a letter that is Q or later; if it does, we double the number associated with that name.

This is what I have so far, with ??? indicating where I know something goes, but not sure what it's called to search for it.

It's homework, so I'm not really looking for answers, but guidance to figure out the right terms to search for my answers.  I already found some stuff on the site (like the statistics functions), but just can't find everything the book doesn't even mention.

```
names = [("Jack",456),("Kayden",355),("Randy",765),("Lisa",635),("Devin",358),("LaWanda",452),("William",308),("Patrcia",256)]

length = len(names)
count = 0

while True
    count < length:
    if ??? > "Q"     # checks if first letter of name is greater than Q
        ???     # doubles number associated with name
    count += 1


print(names)     # self-check

numberNames = names     # creates new list

import statistics
mean = statistics.mean(???)
median = statistics.median(???)

print("Mean value: {0:.2f}".format(mean))

alphaNames = sorted(numberNames)     # sorts names list by name and creates new list

print(alphaNames)
```

Comment: It is not really clear what your program is supposed to do

Comment: He wants us to take a list of names and numbers (we have no idea what the numbers mean, he just gave us names and numbers), have the program check each name to see if it starts with Q or later (so Randy and William), and if it does, double the number associated with the name.  Then display the mean and median for the new numbers, and then print the list in alphabetical order.

This is an intro class, so we're just playing with commands, not doing anything earth shattering.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to iter over your names list. To do so use `for` loop:

```
for person in names:
    print(person)
```

But names are a list of tuples so you will need to get the person name by accessing the first item of the tuple. You do this just like you do with lists

```
name = person[0]
score = person[1]
```

Finally to get the [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) of a character, you use [ord()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord) function. That is going to be helpful to know if name starts with a Q or above.

```
print(ord('A'))
print(ord('Q'))
print(ord('R'))
```

This should be enough informations to get you started with.

Comment: note that ASCII code is case sensitive. 'A' has a different value than 'a'

Comment: OK, awesome, that looks kinda like what I was trying to figure out.  I didn't even think about being able to assign variables to positions in the data.  I'm going to go toss this in and see what it spits out.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few parts to your question, so I'll try to separate them out in my response.

### check if first letter of name is greater than Q

Hopefully this will help you with the syntax here. Like `list`, `str` also supports element access by index with the `[]` syntax.

```
$ names = [("Jack",456),("Kayden",355)]
$ names[0]
('Jack', 456)
$ names[0][0]
'Jack'
$ names[0][0][0]
'J'
$ names[0][0][0] < 'Q'
True
$ names[0][0][0] > 'Q'
False
```

### double number associated with name

```
$ names[0][1]
456
$ names[0][1] * 2
912
```

### "how to refer to just that record that is being changed"

We are trying to update the value associated with the name.

In theme with my previous code examples - that is, we want to update the value at index 1 of the `tuple` stored at index 0 in the `list` called `names`

However, `tuple`s are *immutable* so we have to be a little tricky if we want to use the data structure you're using.

```
$ names = [("Jack",456), ("Kayden", 355)]
$ names[0]
('Jack', 456)
$ tpl = names[0]
$ tpl = (tpl[0], tpl[1] * 2)
$ tpl
('Jack', 912)
$ names[0] = tpl
$ names
[('Jack', 912), ('Kayden', 355)]
```

### Do this for all tuples in the list

We need to do this for the whole list, it looks like you were onto that with your `while` loop. Your *counter* variable for indexing the list is named `count` so just use that to index a specific tuple, like: `names[count][0]` for the count*th* name or `names[count][1]` for the count*th* number.

---

## using `statistics` for calculating `mean` and `median`

I recommend looking at the documentation for a module when you want to know how to use it. Here is an example for `mean`:

> **mean(data)**
>
> Return the sample arithmetic mean of data.

```
    $ mean([1, 2, 3, 4, 4])
    2.8
```

---

Hopefully these examples help you with the syntax for continuing your assignment, although this could turn into a long discussion.

The title of your post is "Need help working with lists within lists" ... well, your code example uses a `list` of `tuple`s

```
$ names = [("Jack",456),("Kayden",355)]
$ type(names)
<class 'list'>
$ type(names[0])
<class 'tuple'>
$ names = [["Jack",456], ["Kayden", 355]]
$ type(names)
<class 'list'>
$ type(names[0])
<class 'list'>
```

notice the difference in the `[]` and `()`

If you are free to structure the data however you like, then I would recommend using a `dict` (read: dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

> I know that you refer to the numbers as names[0][1], names[1][1], etc, but
>   not how to refer to just that record that is being changed. For
>   example, we have to have the program check if a name begins with a
>   letter that is Q or later; if it does, we double the number associated
>   with that name.

It's not entirely clear what else you have to do in this assignment, but regarding your concerns above, to reference the *i*th"record that is being changed" in your `names` list, simply use `names[i]`. So, if you want to access the first record in `names`, simply use `names[0]`, since indexing in Python begins at zero.

Since each element in your list is a `tuple` (which can also be indexed), using constructs like `names[0][0]` and `names[0][1]` are ways to index the values within the tuple, as you pointed out.

I'm unsure why you're using `while True` if you're trying to iterate through each name and check whether it begins with "Q". It seems like a `for` loop would be better, unless your class hasn't gotten there yet.

As for checking whether the first letter is 'Q', `str` (string) objects are indexed similarly to lists and tuples. To access the first letter in a string, for example, see the following:

```
>>> my_string = 'Hello'
>>> my_string[0]
'H'
```

If you give more information, we can help guide you with the `statistics` piece, as well. But I would first suggest you get some background around mean and median (if you're unfamiliar).

Comment: I understand the mean and median, we used it in another project we did (calculating grades), except we actually wrote it out by hand (sum(values) / len(values)).

We haven't gotten to the for command yet, that was supposed to be Tuesday but the school's power went out (yay Florida thunderstorms), so I'll go check that chapter and see if it will help, thanks.